# How to hide particular menu items from master page based on login type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below given code is what i am using for displaying menu items in master page. I do have a login page from where the users login to view the master page menu items. There are different type of users namely "admin,worker,Manager,etc..". I want to hide menu items from master page based on user authentication. If the user logins as "admin" then all menu items should be visible but if the user logins as "worker" then some menu items should be hidden so that they cannot view it. How to do this in a simple way without making it more compicated.

Please help me regarding this situation. I am not an expertise in programming, so explain me in a detailed manner. Thanks in advance.

```
< asp:Menu id="Menu1" runat="server" width="200px" >   
    < Items >  
        < asp:MenuItem Text="EMPLOYEE DETAILS" NavigateUrl="~/Employee_Details.aspx" 
        Value="Employee_Details" >      
        < /asp:MenuItem >  
        < asp:MenuItem Text="INSPECTION" NavigateUrl="~/Inspection_Details.aspx" Value="Inspection" > 
        < /asp:MenuItem >  
        < asp:MenuItem Text="LOGIN DETAILS" NavigateUrl="~/Login_Details.aspx"  Value="Login_Details" >
        < /asp:MenuItem >
        < asp:MenuItem Text="WORK" NavigateUrl="~/WorkInProgress.aspx" Value="Work" >  
        < /asp:MenuItem >  
    < /Items >  
< /asp:Menu >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066046/how-to-disable-specific-menu-item-from-menu-control-in-asp-net-c-sharp-code-behi) a similar Question.

You are using menu .

You can remove an item like

Menu1.Items.Remove

```
var menu = Page.Master.FindControl("Menu1") as Menu;
if(UserStatus != "Admin")
{
 Menu1.Items.Remove(Menu1.FindItem("INSPECTION"));
 Menu1.Items.Remove(Menu1.FindItem("WORK"));
}
```

I suggest you do that in Page_LOad. Please go to the link above or . See  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939031/can-i-hide-show-aspmenu-items-based-on-role?rq=1)  . Its clear . Hope it helps